# Angular2 - Prevent Checkbox from being checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I have a table that contains a checkbox per row. In the table header, I have a `Check All` checkbox that toggles all of the table row boxes.

I am trying to implement some logic to where if the count of checkboxes are going to exceed a specific limit, show an error and don't toggle the table row checkboxes OR the `checkall` box itself.

There is an issue that is allowing the `checkAll` box to get checked, even though I am returning `false`. Issue with my binding?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" [(ngModel)]="checkedAll" (ngModelChange)="toggleAllEmployees($event)">
```

**Component:**

```
toggleAllEmployees(flag) {

    const temp = [];

    if (flag) {

        // If selecting all of these passes the max, throw an error
        if (this.importResults.length > this.maxSelection) {

            /* This is where I get to when I display the error message */
            alert('The number of employees you are trying to select (' + this.importResults.length + ') exceeds the max limit.');
            return false;

        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.importResults.length; i++) {
                if (this.importResults[i].OnTempAssignment !== 'True') {
                    this.importResults[i].checked = true;
                    temp.push(this.importResults[i]);
                }
            }
            this.employeeSelection = temp;

            // Emit our changes
            this.selectedEmployees.emit(this.employeeSelection);

        }
    } else {
        //The else statement just un-checks all the boxes.
    }
}
```

Although none of the table row check boxes get checked, and the error is shown appropriately, the box I am clicking on still gets toggled.

I assumed that the `return false;` would have prevented that but I guess not. Is there something wrong with my binding that is allowing it to be toggled anyway?

Comment: did you try `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @AravindI did and that also did not work. `$event` is only sending a `true/false` bool though, not an actual event object.

Comment: you can also use [**pointer events css**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ngModelChange` is fired when value binded to checkbox has changed, it's late for stop the toggle operation.

Here you should bind with `click` event. Then you can use `$event.preventDefault()` to stop checkbox from been toggled.

---

You can event add some logic before `$event.preventDefault()` to determin whether the checkbox should be prevent from changing status.

see **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/92975DZuog0NhAaqZuRF?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 9):

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" (click)="onClick($event)">
```

Code

```
onClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();

 // In my case, I'm using the popup.
 // so once user confirms then hits api and update checkbox value.
 this.isChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the best and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a similar problem but check if the limit has reached then prevented the default preventDefault() and stopped stopPropagation()

```
<input type="checkbox" class="message-checkbox mr-2" (click)="stopCheckingStates($event)"
                        (change)="stateChange(state, $event)" [checked]="isStateChecked(state.id)">
```

then in the ts file

```
    stopCheckingStates(event){
    this.stopCheckingCheckBox(event, 1);
  }

  stopCheckingCheckBox = (event, limit) => {
    if (selectArray.length > limit) {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      } else {

      }

    }
  }
```

so you can set your limit as required for my case its was one