# uncheck a checkbox which is in a for loop through a method

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, checkbox

I am having a checkbox inside a for loop and having a array to store the row details. I only wants to select two checkboxes at a time. when a user clicked on the 3rd checkbox, checkbox should be unchecked automatically while giving a toaster messege.

I have tried to implement this and am getting the toaster messege successfully. But 3rd checkbox is not getting unchecked automatically. Please help on this.

HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows$; let indexOfEl = index">

    <td><input type="checkbox" value="indexOfEl (change)="onCheckboxChange($event,indexOfEl,row)"/></td>

</tr>
```

TS file

```
onCheckboxChange(event: any, index:any, data: any){

  if(event?.target?.checked){

      if(this.selectedCommand.length < 2){

      data.index = index;

      this.selectedCommand.push(data);

 }

 else {

        this.sharedService.showErrorNotification('Cannot select more than two commands', 'Error');

     }

}

  else this.selectedCommand = this.arrayRemove(this.selectedCommand,index);}

arrayRemove(array:any , index:any){

return array.filter(function(element){

  return element.index != index;

});
```

}

Comment: Could you also please provide the 'arrayRemove' function?

Comment: @IishfaaqIsmath please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: have you tried setting event.target.checked = false in the else clause?

Comment: @alexfar yes i did but its not working

Comment: ok, you could bind the checked value of the mat-checkbox in your html form to a function which checks if it should be checked or not. For example you can create a function called isChecked(id: string){ return this.selectedCommand.find(id);} and then change the input html definition as follows <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked(row.id)" value="indexOfEl (change)="onCheckboxChange($event,indexOfEl,row)"/> or something similar

Comment: @Slikhut I have edited the question with arrayRemove function

Comment: @alexfar That solution does not work either

Comment: @Slikhut, refer to verified answer on this question, i think the easiest way to do it would be to bind to the click event instead of the change/ checked event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726725/angular2-prevent-checkbox-from-being-checked

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly wrote it out how i would do it. Feel free to use this if it helps.

HTML

```
  <tr *ngFor="let command of commands">
    <td>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, command)"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

TS

```
export class YourComponent {
  public selectedCommand: Command[] = [];
  public commands: Command[] = [
    { commandName: 'Command 1' },
    { commandName: 'Command 2' },
    { commandName: 'Command 3' },
    { commandName: 'Command 4' },
    { commandName: 'Command 5' }
  ];

  constructor() { } 

  public onCheckboxChange(event: any, data: Command) {
    if (event?.target?.checked) {
      if (this.selectedCommand.length < 2) {
        this.selectedCommand.push(data);
      }
      else {
        this.sharedService.showErrorNotification('Cannot select more than two commands', 'Error');
        event.target.checked = false;
      }
    }
    else {
      var indexToRemove = this.selectedCommand.findIndex(x => x.commandName == data.commandName);
      this.selectedCommand.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
  }

}

interface Command {
  commandName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck a checkbox like this:

```
public onCheckboxChange(event: any, data: Command) {
  event.source.checked = false;
}
```

Here is another way:

```
public onCheckboxChange(event: any, data: Command) {
  event.target.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more Angular approach: using [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)

```
<li *ngFor="let row of rows$; let indexOfEl = index">
    <!--use a template reference variable "checkID"-->
    <input #checkID type="checkbox" [value]="indexOfEl" 
                [ngModel]="selectedCommand.indexOf(indexOfEl)>=0" 
                <!--you pass to the ngModelChange the "checkID"-->
                (ngModelChange)="onCheckboxChange(checkID,row)"/>
</li>
```

The function onCheckboxChange

```
onCheckboxChange(checkID: any,data: any) {
    //store the old value
    const oldValue=this.selectedCommand;
    if (!checkID.checked)
      this.selectedCommand=oldValue.filter((x:any)=>x!=data.index)
    else
    {
      if (this.selectedCommand.length>1)
      {
        alert('Cannot select more than two commands');
          checkID.checked=false;
      }
      else
      {
        this.selectedCommand=this.rows$.map(x=>x.index)
                          .filter((x:any)=>x==data.index || oldValue.indexOf(x)>=0)
      }
    }
  }
```

This allow as, at very first defined our variable selectedComand as, e.g.

```
selectedCommand=[0,2]
```

To show the checked values

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-apffzk?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: Don't forget import the FormsModule to use ngModel

NOTE2: generally in Angular you use the suffix "$" when a variable is an observable